# Need for unusual string concatenation in C or C++ for microcontroller display driver

Tags: c++, string, char, concatenation

I'm adding string and text support to Dean Reading's "[SevSeg](https://github.com/DeanIsMe/SevSeg)" display driver for [7-segment displays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display), controlled by Arduino, and I need some help.

Due to limitations on the display, I have to create special cases where two digits on the display are used to display one character. Ex: "M" must be treated as a special case since one display digit cannot create an M by itself.

What I need essentially is for the user to be able to write something like this:

```
char myString[] = "Help Me Do This!";
```

Except that I want them to be able to specify whether they want to use the special M (called "PSEUDO_M") instead. If they leave the above phrase as-is, the M will be replaced with a dash, and I don't want to prohibit this behavior since the user may want the phrase to fit in a set # of display digits more than they want a 2-digit M. Anyway, what I want is something like this:

```
const char PSEUDO_M = -128;

char myString[] = "Help " + PSEUDO_M + "e Do this!";
//OR perhaps:
char myString[] = "Help [PSEUDO_M]e Do this!";
```

I would then process their input string, treating the PSEUDO_M (dec -128) as a special case.

Obviously, the above additions of strings doesn't work in C.

I know that a string is simply a char array, so when a user creates a string, the character decimal representation for the above (WITH the PSEUDO_M [-128] used in place of the M [77]) would be:

```
char myString[] = {72, 101, 108, 112, 32, -128, 101, 32, 68, 111, 32, 84, 104, 105, 115, 33, 0};
```

However, the above number array is not human-readable. ***The idea is that the user types in a string literal essentially, using standard characters. So, what's the best way to write a macro, function, or something else that will easily allow someone to type a phrase to be used in a string, but where M's (dec 77) will be replaced with PSEUDO_M's (dec -128), *if* the user desires it?***

**Note:** ideally, the technique I use will not take up any extra bytes in the char array, since my PSEUDO_M could simply be represented as a single character (dec -128).

Comment: Please only tag your question with either the `c` or the `c++` tag, not both; they are separate languages.

Comment: How do I deal with the fact that it is a microcontroller (Arduino in this case) and supports a lot of C++, but not all of it, but can otherwise use C? Should I just say it's C++? It uses gcc C++ compiler, but much of the Arduino core is written in pure C and uses the extern C thing in the header....but then again I guess most libraries (incl this one) use C++ classes.

Comment: Using the `extern "C"` doesn't make the code c. It's not valid in c actually, it's used to let the compiler know that this code will link to c code and prevent it from mangling the symbols.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, technically I'm using C++, but chances are the best answer will be written in pure C, based on all my past experience, so I'm hesitant to take out the "C" tag while leaving the C++ one.

Comment: How are you compiling it? I suspect the compiler supports the full C++ language, but the standard library is unavailable. If that's the case, then the c++ tag is still appropriate. Alternatively, check your source code file extension.

Comment: I'm using .cpp on the source code. I'll remove the C tag.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, thanks for the answer. Now that we see the final answer (yours) is a pure C code answer, should I have left the C tag in and taken out the C++ tag? What's most likely going to help trigger the right people to give the right answers in cases like this? I hope you see my dilemma: I'm writing C-style and C++ code on a microcontroller, using a C++ compiler, but I thought I wanted a pure C answer, and I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in C, multiple character literals in sequence are concatenated by the compiler; for example, `"foo" "bar"` is the same as `"foobar"`.

Using this and a define, you can get a syntax that's human readable while still having zero runtime overhead.

```
#define PSEUDO_M "\xAB" // Replace AB with the appropriate code

char myString[] = "Help " PSEUDO_M "e Do this!";
```

Comment: This is also true, and it's probably useful to the OP. But it doesn't mean that my answer is wrong. Even though the question is tagged with [tag:c++] and someone could answer that the OP can write a class and overload the `+` operator, etc.

Comment: I need PSEUDO_M to be decimal -128, I"m not familiar with the \ being used like this (I've only used \" before). Looking it up on Google now.

Comment: I found the backslash thing. http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0035.htm. I don't suppose I can do this with DEC instead of HEX?

Comment: It works; thanks! Here's the actual define that produces -128: `#define PSEUDO_M "\x80"`

Comment: Another useful link for readers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C